# Twitter can_dm returns null on Web API

Tags: api, twitter, null

When I inspect Twitter requests on a web page (members of list) it returns well-prepared user list with length 20.

https://prnt.sc/ottze7

But when I inspect an account's detailed information from the response, the data `can_dm` assigned to `null` as `can_dm=null`, normally as far as I know it should return some boolean data which will tell me if I can DM to the user or not.

https://prnt.sc/ottzw7

The questions are:
1. Why it doesn't work properly and how can I fix it?
or
2. How can I walk around this problem and learn if I can DM to them or not?

Comment: Are you signed in as one of the users you're interested in? You cannot find out if one arbitrary user can DM another, but if you're authenticated as one of them, that field should be true or false. This is known as a perspectival attribute.

Comment: I'm logged in on my browser which I inspect the network request, if that's what you are asking?

Comment: I can only help you with the official Twitter API and OAuth. Sniffing the network requests for the browser is not a supported way of interacting with Twitter.